# SwiftUI - Position and Size Issue with Signature Overlay on Zoomable Image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, snapshot

I'm developing an iOS app using SwiftUI, and I've encountered a challenge while working on it. I have an image in the app that can be zoomed in and out, and I'm trying to add a signature overlay to this image. However, I'm facing a few issues:

1. The signature always appears centered on the image, but I want it to
   be positioned at a specific location.
2. The size of the signature remains constant regardless of the zoom
   level of the image. I want it to scale along with the image [like here](https://imgur.com/a/poaVslY).
3. After taking a snapshot, the background image shrinks gradually.

Problem 1 and 3 provided [here](https://imgur.com/a/bgVFWz0).

I've shared the relevant code below. Could someone please help me understand what's going wrong and guide me on how to address these issues?

```
// MARK: - SNAPSHOT LOGIC
extension View {
    func snapshot(withSize targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Starting View
struct AddingSignatureView3: View {
    
    @State var chosenSignature: UIImage = UIImage()
    @Binding var scannedImage: UIImage
    
    @State private var signatureOffset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            ZStack {
                
                ScannedImageView(scannedImage: $scannedImage, signatureOffset: $signatureOffset)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        // This is for seeing the immediate result of the snapshot
                        scannedImage = ScannedImageView(scannedImage: $scannedImage, signatureOffset: $signatureOffset).snapshot(withSize: scannedImage.size)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Image with Signature in ZStack
struct ScannedImageView: View {
    
    @Binding var scannedImage: UIImage
    @Binding var signatureOffset: CGSize
    
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var scaleAnchor: UnitPoint = .center
    @State private var lastScale: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var debug = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            let magnificationGesture = MagnificationGesture()
                .onChanged{ gesture in
                    scaleAnchor = .center
                    scale = lastScale * gesture
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
                }
            
            let dragGesture = DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    var newOffset = lastOffset
                    newOffset.width += gesture.translation.width
                    newOffset.height += gesture.translation.height
                    offset = newOffset
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
                }
            
            ZStack {
                Image(uiImage: scannedImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2,
                              y: geometry.size.height / 2)
                    .scaleEffect(scale, anchor: scaleAnchor)
                    .offset(offset)
                    .gesture(dragGesture)
                    .gesture(magnificationGesture)
                
                DraggableSignatureView(signatureOffset: $signatureOffset)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: GeometryProxy) {
        let newScale: CGFloat = .minimum(.maximum(scale, 1), 4)
        let screenSize = geometry.size
        
        let originalScale = scannedImage.size.width / scannedImage.size.height >= screenSize.width / screenSize.height ?
        geometry.size.width / scannedImage.size.width :
        geometry.size.height / scannedImage.size.height
        
        let imageWidth = (scannedImage.size.width * originalScale) * newScale
        
        var width: CGFloat = .zero
        if imageWidth > screenSize.width {
            let widthLimit: CGFloat = imageWidth > screenSize.width ?
            (imageWidth - screenSize.width) / 2
            : 0
            
            width = offset.width > 0 ?
                .minimum(widthLimit, offset.width) :
                .maximum(-widthLimit, offset.width)
        }
        
        let imageHeight = (scannedImage.size.height * originalScale) * newScale
        var height: CGFloat = .zero
        if imageHeight > screenSize.height {
            let heightLimit: CGFloat = imageHeight > screenSize.height ?
            (imageHeight - screenSize.height) / 2
            : 0
            
            height = offset.height > 0 ?
                .minimum(heightLimit, offset.height) :
                .maximum(-heightLimit, offset.height)
        }
        
        let newOffset = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        lastScale = newScale
        lastOffset = newOffset
        withAnimation() {
            offset = newOffset
            scale = newScale
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Signature View
struct DraggableSignatureView: View {
    @Binding var signatureOffset: CGSize
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill") // You can replace this with your signature view
            .font(.system(size: 48))
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .offset(signatureOffset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        signatureOffset = CGSize(
                            width: gesture.translation.width,
                            height: gesture.translation.height
                        )
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

I was able to achieve taking a right snapshot with different function, but It scaled my image to the size of the iPhone screen and not the real size of the image, so I need to avoid this result.

I've tried to control the position and size of the signature using the signatureOffset variable, but it's not working as expected. The signature is always centered, and its size doesn't change with the image zoom. How can I modify this code to achieve the desired behavior?

Thank you for your help!